# Unir dois array em php

Tags: php, array

Bom dia galera, uma dúvida rápida. Preciso Unir dois array de uma consultas da seguinte maneira:

```
$tamanhos = array('p', 'm', 'g');
$valor_item = array('10', '20', '30');
```

onde "p" tem que ser igual a 10, m = 20, g = 30

Isso para pode fazer um foreach que una os dois arrays para exibir o tamanho com o valor de cada item.

Acho que assim daria para entender melhor o que preciso.

Obrigado e no aguardo.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo de como você quer que fique, não está claro. Esse seu exemplo nem tem arrays (se levar a sério a sintaxe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada revise a sintaxe de arrays.

```
$tamanhos = array('p', 'm', 'g');
$valor = array('10', '20', '30');
$result = array_combine($tamanhos, $valor);

print_r($result);
```

[**rodando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/Iev2K7)

**Resultado:**

```
Array
(
    [p] => 10
    [m] => 20
    [g] => 30
)
```

[a**rray_combine**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) — Cria um array usando um array para chaves e outro para valores

Comment: @Saulo, se a resposta está certa marque como aceita ou de um exemplo de como seria o resultado na sua pergunta